# angular 11 custom accessible assets folder

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 11 and with this configuration I can set custom accessible assets folder and it works on local, but when I build project with "ng build --prod" and upload it on the server it seems the folder is not accessible.

```
"build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/Linkeee",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "aot": true,
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/manifest.webmanifest",
          {"glob": "**/*", "input": "D:/images", "output": "./assets/"}
          
          
        ],
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
          "src/custom-theme.scss",
          "src/styles.css"
          
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.min.js"
        ]
      },
```

I defined "D:/images" as "assets".
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

there is no such method. Your Angular application starts from the directory "angular.json" file. You can only use any file on your local machine in `development` environment. These paths will be invalid in the `production` environment. The best method is to move the files contained in 'D:\images' into 'src/images' or `src/assets/images` and changes

```
"assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/manifest.webmanifest",
          {"glob": "**/*", "input": "src/images/**", "output": "./assets/"}
          
          
        ],
```

Comment: thanks, but I have an issue that I want to show images that are uploaded by an other application in an other directory. what should I do for this?